# ssd not working after failed hdparm

Tags: gparted, ssd, hdparm

So I followed the instructions (exactly) from [this](https://grok.lsu.edu/Article.aspx?articleid=16716) article but when I typed the last command:

"If the drive DOES support Enhanced Security Erase, type:"

```
hdparm --user-master u --security-erase-enhanced p /dev/sda
```

it instantly outputted the text it outputs when you type just the hdparm command on its own (it just listed all the arguments I can use it with etc). Still I left it there for about an hour (in a previous command result it said it would take approximately 8 minutes for the enhanced erase) but then I closed the terminal because I was sure something was wrong (also on closing the terminal a window warned me that a process is running, I killed it). After a reboot, the disk was discoverable in bios, but fdisk does not show it and gparted comes up with there 3 error messages:

```
Libparted Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sda
Libparted Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sda
Libparted Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
```

Upon pressing "retry", "ignore", "cancel" a bunch of times I can finally see the disk in gparted with 1 unallocated partition which I can't create partition tables cause if I try it once again shows all these error messages and in the end "error creating partition (or something like this)".

So, how do I format the disk? I don't care about the data. I just want to install windows on it.

- Disk: Samsung EVO 750 500GB
- I am in a live usb Ubuntu 16
- SSD is connected on a SATA internally
- I also tried just installing ubuntu or windows on it but again, errors come up of the I/O nature (can't create partition)

Comment: If I were you, I would try the other `--security???` options one by one (refer to `man hdparm`) and see if I can unlock the disk, in the meantime checking if the disk is readable (`head /dev/sda` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was locked (saw it after I ran the "hdparm -I /dev/sda" command, thanks to @FedonKadifeli). So then I ran the command

```
hdparm --security-unlock PASSWORD /dev/sda
```

using the password I used initially ("p") and it unlocked. Then I entered the command:

```
time hdparm --user-master u --security-erase PASSWORD /dev/sda
```

Essentially, I had left the procedure in the middle.

Afterwards it was visible in gparted without errors and warnings, so I was able to create a partition table and format it to ntfs normally. I closed the terminal (even though it still warned me about a process running) and the disk is fine again. Files are wiped and I don't know if the secure wipe succeeded but at this point I don't care. I will just connect it to a windows PC and just use samsung magician.

Maybe this question is due for a duplicate question flag but anyway. I'm glad I saved my drive and this was the way.

Lesson from this: Not messing with hdparm again.